# What is the correct way of sorting NSFetchedResultsController values?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have NSFetchedResultsController and I want to sort the values in it alphabetically. And I want to use it later as:

```
if let myItems = frc.object(at: indexPath) as? MyItem { ... }
```

I'm trying to sort it like this:

```
var new = frc.fetchedObjects?.sorted(by: {($0 as! MyItem).name < ($1 as! MyItem).name})
```

but it creates an array of [NSFetchRequestResult]. But I need to use sections as well. In one sentence: want just sort my FRC and to get in a result a normal FRC with the previous structure, not an array. How can I correct my code?

Comment: The usual way is to assign `sortDescriptors` to the controller. And if you want to get the proper `NSManagedObject` subclass you have to specify the generic type.

Comment: is there any sortDescriptor for sorting it alphabetically? I could not find it @vadian

Comment: It's the same pattern as the `sorted` way: `NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)`

Comment: @vadian I've tried `if let frc = fetchedResultsController {
            let alphabeticalSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
            frc.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [alphabeticalSortDescriptor]` but does not work. Is something wrong here?

Comment: After changing the sortdescriptor you need to refetch the data.